# Show "Saving...." animation on screen while saving a record into the database

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

To my knowledge, there can be two possible ways to design this:

1. Using a gif file. Once the Save button is clicked, it should show the "Saving..." gif file on screen for a few seconds(delay is hardcoded) and then the process of saving the record to the database should start. Ideally Speaking, this would lessen the performance as it takes time for both Animation delay + Saving the record.
2. Multithreading. Saving a record and animation should be done parallel.I do not have any idea about how to do this.

Which is possible?

Kindly, share some information and code snippets. Also, post any other idea which can resolve this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think first one is better..
put the below code in page then when clciking the button load the corresponding div id.

```
        <div id="divLoading" class="loading-div">
            <img id="imgLoading" class="loading-img" src="images/loading.gif"" />
            <span>Just a moment...</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can we make this division to appear highlighted and the rest of the page as faded out? if so, how?

Comment: give the div style to display none initially, then when loading the div through javascript or another way change the style to block.

Answer (score 1):

use this plugin instead

[jquery plugin message](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-message/)

[Live Demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/message/demo/)

Comment: The link to the demo and in the page are dead

Answer (score 0):

Second one is easy to do do:

Use JQUERY api,

For more information: [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php", // here server side saving code will be here.
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

In the mean time, you just need to show the image which is GIF like Loading... and then save it.